# R rows unanalysed

Tags: r, rows

So I'm trying to format my xls data in a way that the first row will be seen in R, but it won't be analysed as in this example: http://bowtie-bio.sourceforge.net/recount/ExpressionSets/bodymap_eset.RData

When you open the exprs(bm) expression data in this the first row gives you the gene names, but these aren't e.g. being log transformed.

I formatted my own data into a similar table, but cannot figure out how to omit the first table from showing up in R and more importantly being used in calculations, which of course results in error codes all the way.

Hope that makes sense?

Cheers

Comment: Please consider referring to [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1655567) and making your post reproducible.

Comment: No, unfortunately, it does not make sense. When I tried to look at your data, I see nothing since I don't have `Biobase` installed, so I second @Konrad's request. Your description is a little confusing, too: you first talk about *"the first row"* but then ask *"how to omit the first table"*. If you are using Excel to edit/create CSV files, is it critical that you are using bioconductor, or is this just about getting data into R?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the first column, not the rows (R beginner here). So let me rephrase: the first column isn't numeric. I'd like R not to consider it in a calculation when using the data. So how do I omit the first column from being read. There must be a way. E.g. when you load data into R Studio, it asks you to use the first "row" for names. I'd like the same to happen for the first column.